# MySQL Error 1292: Truncated Incorrect Double Value

Tags: mysql, database

Yes, I know this question has been asked a thousand times. But I cannot for the life of me figure out why this query is not working.

This query takes an input latitude and longitude and selects the closest 25 buildings in the database.  Here is the code:

```
set @lat = 37.422003;
set @lng = -122.084059;

drop table if exists `test`.`results`;
create table `test`.`results` (address varchar(255), city varchar(100), state char(2), zip char(5), lat decimal(15,10), lng decimal(15,10), distance decimal(6,2));
insert into `test`.`results` select address, city, state, zip, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( @lat ) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians( @lng ) ) + sin( radians( @lat ) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) as distance from `test`.`buildings` having distance < 25 limit 0, 25;
```

When I run the above statements, I get the MySQL error 1292 (I'm in strict mode). All of the columns in the select statement are the exact same datatypes as the ones in the create statement. The problem seems to be the distance calculation but I am not seeing anything incorrect with it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Would you please provide the DDL for table `buildings` ? Also, if you remove the math operations that computes the `distance` from the query (replace it with `NULL` for example), do you still encounter the same error ?

Comment: If I comment out the calculation and insert the rest of the data, it works correctly. As for the DDL, what information would you like? The DDL I know of is `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, `TRUNCATE`, `COMMENT`, `RENAME`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `buildings` table.

Comment: `create table test.buildings (address varchar(255), city varchar(100), state char(2), zip char(5), lat decimal(15,10), lng decimal(15,10));`